# Block commit after Update/Insert for 10 million records being processed

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Requirements need an Update and Insert for 10 million records in Sql Server 2005.
I have created a Stored Procedure using T-SQL.
Do we need to do a commit after the process above , say 10000 records committed at at time. If so how do I write a commit statement for say every 10000 records.
Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: How many times/often do you have to do this?

Comment: Will there be any concurrent readers of the table that you want to avoid blocking through lock escalation? Does your transaction log disc have plenty of space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, a way to do batch deletes/updates/inserts is to use a `WHILE` loop.  The pattern I normally follow is:

```
WHILE 1=1
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable
 (field1, field2, field3...)
 SELECT TOP 100000 (field1, field2, field3...)
 FROM dbo.MySourceTableorQuery as S
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM dbo.SourceTableorQuery as S 
        WHERE s.PrimaryKey = MyTable.PrimaryKey)
 IF @@ROWCOUNT<100000 BREAK;
END
```

As to "whether you need to", that's impossible to answer without a lot of other information.  What kind of query is it, what's  the table structure like, how long does it take to run currently, how are you for disk space (you will really increase the size of tempdb if it's a single transaction), how wide is the table you are inserting to, etc?